# Workflow on Last Activity Date

Tags: workflow, account, event

is it possible to set a workflow that would create a task or email alert if there was no activity e.g. for the last 180 days...? By activity I mean only logging a task or event not editing the account itself... seems to be a tricky one. could anybody give me some tips how to approach the problem?

Thank you in advance

Pawel

Comment: I'm not an expert with Workflows, but maybe you could set a time-based workflow on the `Last Modified Date`: set the trigger to fire 180 days after the `Last Modified Date`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert with Workflows, but maybe you could set a time-based workflow on the `Last Modified Date`: set the trigger to fire 180 days after the `Last Modified Date`.  But this rule would have to be re-evaluated every time the record is UPDATED (as to reset the <kbd>180-days-after-the-Last-Modification Clock</kbd>)

Comment: The question specifically refers to `Last Activity Date` not `Last Modified Date`.

Comment: jesus, what to do?

Comment: I'm not sure if your comment was sarcastic, but it is actually an important distinction.  If you go to the time-based workflow trigger create page you'll see that `LastActivityDate` is not an option.